# Does anything related to activity/participation earned on one SE site extend across all SE sites?

Tags: support, reputation

Are there any instances that if I earn a point, a badge, or a privilege on one Stack Exchange site that I'll find that I've earned it across the entire SE network?

Are there any instances that if I earn a point, a badge, or a privilege on one Stack Exchange site that I'll find that I've earned it on any of the other SE sites I'm a member of at the time I earn it/them?

Secondarily, do all of the SE sites offer/have all of the same badges, privileges and point structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one thing that crosses sites, that I know of, and that's only partial, so to speak. If you have earned 200 or more reputation points on any one site, then you are given 100 bonus points on any site you join. It will also apply to other sites you have already joined, in that your rep on the other sites will jump 100 points.

Of note, however, is that those 100 points will not enable you to post answers on "protected" questions. Such questions have a note on them reminding users that they require 10 rep points from *that* site, and that the association bonus does not apply.

Something else that "looks" like it carries from site to site is the ability to chat in the chat rooms for a site. That is misleading, however, since the chat system is connected to the network as a whole rather than each site. So, once you have enough rep to use chat, it's for chat everywhere. [As noted in [another answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1417/27) by [Catija ♦](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36/catija) this is 20 rep points, which can be from several sites, not just one, and Stack Overflow, and Meta Stack Exchange are on different servers, so require their own 20 points. Once you get the association bonus above, you'll have the 20+ everywhere anyway.]

As to the badges and privileges and point structure, it's *mostly* the same. Actually there are 4 different point-to-privilege scales. Most "graduated" sites use one scale, public beta sites (such as this one) have a 2nd scale, private beta sites have a 3rd scale, and Stack Overflow has its own 4th scale.

Private beta sites have the "easiest" scale which is mostly doubled for public beta sites. That, in turn is mostly doubled for the rest of the sites (most graduated sites). <strike>Because of its size, Stack Overflow has an even higher scale, although most things on the lower end (where I get to operate) seem to be the same as other graduated sites.</strike> <sub>See the answer by Catija ♦ for this correction.</sub>

You can see what the point scale is for any site by adding `help/privileges` to the URL. So for this site, `https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/` the scale is at [`https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges`](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

As far as I know, the badges are the same for all sites - in spirit anyway. There are badges for earning enough votes in a given tag, obviously each site has its own set of tags, but the idea of a badge for answers in a tag is on each site. Though they have the same badges, earning a badge on one site will not give you that badge on another site. Badges incentivize participation on the site rather than the SE network as a whole. (If you update your profile you get a badge for that, Autobiographer, and when signing up for a different site your profile is copied, so you "automatically" get Autobiographer on that site as well.) Most badges are not based on reputation points directly, though some have minimum vote scores on questions or answers. To earn some badges requires privileges, which are tied to reputation points as well, however.

Comment: As I am presently in the process of replying (in another browser tab), in the affirmative, to a meta question on whether we should increase our down-voting, I am quite curious why this answer received a down-vote. The gist of my answer is that down-voting will work as a deterrent to poor answers. If I am successful in convincing people thus, I hope answers like this, and the people who take the time to write them, will not be the recipients. I believe down-voting is anonymous for good reason, but I am curious what the problem is with this answer. I appreciated it, @Witan, and will counter w/+.

Comment: The bonus applies to all sites, new and old, so you can remove the "I think"

Comment: You mean protected questions, not "locked" ones, I think?

Comment: @Catija Again, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Once you earn the [chat privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257816/demystifying-chat-reputation-requirements) (20 rep), it allows you to chat on every site that is on that chat server. MSE and SO are on their own chat servers. All of the other sites are on the same one. So, you have to earn 20 rep on each server to be able to use chat everywhere or, once you have 200 rep on one site, you will be able to use all three. Note, the 20 reputation for chat does not need to be earned on the same site - 10 reputation on one site and five each on two others will give you access to chat (or if you're really not interested in earning reputation, joining 20 sites will do it, too).

Earning 200 reputation on one site gives you an immediate +100 reputation (the "[association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)") on all sites you're currently a member of and all future sites you join. It is designed to give you most of the basic abilities everywhere.

In general, badges, reputation, and privileges are earned on a per-site basis. The exception I can think of is the seasonal special event Winterbash. Earning a hat on one site allows you to use it on all sites.

There are three types of sites, each with their [own reputation levels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) - private beta are the lowest, public beta are what apply here and are in the middle, and sites that have a custom design. "Graduated" sites that do not have a custom design also [do not get the privilege reputation level increases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september?rq=1). Other than that, though, all of the sites are the same.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) has additional reputation triggers for privileges relating to documentation and removing advertisements but the only level that's different is that creating a tag requires 1500 reputation instead of 300 on graduated sites with a design.

Answer (score -2):

No.

Yes and no. They don't translate to other sites, but do for Chat.

And no. Private beta, public beta, and graduated sites have different rep values for privies, but they do all have the same privileges and almost all the same badges. No site specific badges, aside from Tag Badges.

See [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-co)

Keep in mind, once a site moves up, the privileges you gain could be lost once the new rep level is pushed out, based on your rep.

Comment: "Keep in mind, once a site moves up, the privileges you gain could be lost once the new rep level is pushed out, based on your rep." That's a fine nuance – thanks for the attention to detail.